# Increasing Postgres column name length

Tags: windows, postgresql

While coding, I realized Postgres has a column name limitation of 63 bytes and anything more than that will be truncated.
based on the article on web, I have changed NAMEDATALEN to 301(remember column name length is always NAMEDATALEN – 1) src/include/pg_config_manual.h to increase the column name length.

The PostgreSQL pg_config_manual.h file contains various configuration symbols and limits.   If you edit any of these, be sure to do a *full* * rebuild (and an initdb if noted).

I am clueless for me how to do full rebuild or initdb after changing .h file in windows.

Can anyone help me to complete this task?

I am using postgres 12 Windows one (refer the link for exact version https://www.postgresql.org/download/windows/)

Comment: First, the fact that you think you need a column name of 300 bytes is an indication of a problem. Running queries with columns names of that length is going to be a nightmare. Second, to recompile you need a development environment on Windows and that is  another nightmare. Third, where are you getting the source? I would seriously rethink this entire idea or at least provide some sort of compelling reason for doing this.

Comment: Can you succesfully build? Do you need help about build or only for full rebuild?

Comment: I need the help for rebuild...since I have changed in pg_config_manual.h file to increase the column size. ***** I am working in window's environment****

Answer (score 0):

That means that you have to compile, link and install PostgreSQL from the source code. You cannot use binary installation packages that way (unless you roll your own).

This is definitely possible and not even complicated if you have an idea of software development in C, but I would reconsider the requirement in your place.